# SQL, backward fill only for first nulls, forward fill only for last nulls, linear interpolation for other nulls

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, imputation

How do I fill backward, forward, and linear interpolation of a column in a table that has column timestamp in bigquery?

I have this table:

| timestamp | mycol |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | 69 |
| 4 | null |
| 5 | 71 |
| 6 | 72 |
| 7 | null |

I expect outcome like this:

| timestamp | mycol |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 69 |
| 2 | 69 |
| 3 | 69 |
| 4 | 70 |
| 5 | 71 |
| 6 | 72 |
| 7 | 72 |

Comment: So if there exists earlier non-null value you should take that, if not, take the next latest non-null value?

Comment: @Error_2646 correct!

Comment: in the expected outcome, where timestamp value is 4, why does mycol value is 70(incremented by 1 to previous value 69)  and same is not the case where where timestamp value is 7, here should it be 73 or 72

Comment: @BihagKashikar because the NULL at timestamp is 4 is filled by linear interpolation

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira see my updated query below, see if that helped. I am keen to know. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see below query, the result is inspired from https://justrocketscience.com/post/interpolation_sql/ however, my query handles the nulls if last row is a null

```
 WITH input_data as (
  SELECT 1 as _timestamp,   null as my_col
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as _timestamp,   null as my_col
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 as _timestamp,   69 as my_col
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 as _timestamp,   null as my_col
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 as _timestamp,   71 as my_col
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 as _timestamp,   72 as my_col
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 as _timestamp,   null as my_col
) SELECT *,
    cast(case when input_data.my_col is not null then input_data.my_col
        when lag(input_data.my_col) over (ORDER BY _timestamp, my_col) is not null and 
            lead(input_data.my_col) over (ORDER BY _timestamp, my_col) is not null 
            then ( lag(input_data.my_col) over (ORDER BY _timestamp, my_col) + 
                lead(input_data.my_col) over (ORDER BY _timestamp, my_col) ) / 2
        else IFNULL(FIRST_VALUE(my_col IGNORE NULLS)  OVER (item_window ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ),
                    LAG(my_col) OVER (ORDER BY _timestamp, my_col))
        end 
        as int64)
        as new_value 
FROM input_data
WINDOW item_window as (ORDER BY input_data._timestamp)
```

See query output in the screenshot

[image]